# How to show nearest div id for a given input number?

Tags: javascript, css, html

Let's say I have the following input field:

```
<input id="inputField" type="number" value="">
```

and some divs such as:

```
<div id="1000"></div>
<div id="1200"></div>
<div id="1500"></div>
<div id="1900"></div>
...
```

When the user enters a number in the input field, I want my code to go to the nearest div id to that number.

e.g:  If user enters 1300 then show div with id = "1200".

What's the most efficient way to implement that in javascript considering there will be a large number of divs?

Right now I'm doing:

```
<script>
        function myFunction() 
        {
            var x = document.getElementById("inputField").value;

            if(x >= 1750 && x <= 1900) 
            {
                window.location.hash = '#1800';
            }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have list of all ids you have in document?

Comment: Yes, I do. I'm entering those ids manually.

Comment: Is it any different than giving them all an id and finding the closest id?

Comment: Much more fun if you didn't have static list of ids: https://jsfiddle.net/wc5pc40u/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to wrap all your divs with number ids in another div if you can (and give it some id, say 'numbers'); this allows you to find all the divs in your javascript file.

### Javascript:

```
// Get all the divs with numbers, if they are children of div, id="numbers"
let children = document.getElementById('numbers').children;

let array = [];
for (i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    // Append the integer of the id of every child to an array
    array.push(parseInt(children[i].id));
}

// However you are getting your input number goes here
let number = 1300  // Replace
currentNumber = array[0]
for (const value of array){
    if (Math.abs(number - value) < Math.abs(number - currentNumber)){
        currentNumber = value;
    }
}

// You say you want your code to go to the nearest div,
// I don't know what you mean by go to, but here is the div of the closest number
let target = document.getElementById(currentNumber.toString());
```

Let me know if there's more I can add to help.

### Demo

```js
function closestNum() {

  let children = document.getElementById('numbers').children;

  let array = [];
  for (i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    array.push(parseInt(children[i].id));
  }

  let number = document.getElementById('inputnum').value;
  currentNumber = array[0]
  for (const value of array) {
    if (Math.abs(number - value) < Math.abs(number - currentNumber)) {
      currentNumber = value;
    }
  }

  let target = document.getElementById(currentNumber.toString());

  document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = target.innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<div id="numbers">
  <div id="1000">1000</div>
  <div id="2000">2000</div>
  <div id="3000">3000</div>
  <div id="4000">4000</div>
  <div id="5000">5000</div>
</div>

<br />
<input type="text" id="inputnum" placeholder="Input Number" onchange="closestNum()" />

<br />
<br /> Target:
<div id="target"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Jeremy, I can't make your code run. I get a NULL value for target and NaN for currentNumber. https://jsfiddle.net/gtdk07L5/4/

Comment: @MarkPazovic You have to change some of the lines to fit whatever HTML you have. I assume that would be the issue, but I'll set up a demo to show you (or maybe figure out I messed up)

Comment: @MarkPazovic thanks for pointing the issue out.  I used `element.childNodes` instead of `element.children` and wasn't getting the appropriate properties from the objects returned from childNodes, if I were to use that. You can see in the demo it works now, though it is a pretty pathetic demo

Comment: If it is guaranteed that ids appear in ascending order then you can break the loop early. A given input e.g. `15xx` can match `1000` or `2000` so you can breakout of the loop after `2000`.

Comment: @SalmanA absolutely. Making sure the numbers are in ascending order in the array (you could also sort the array for that regardless of what order the divs are in) and cutting it off is a great way to optimize time, but for the sake of simplicity, I didn't want to include more than necessary in the code.

Answer (score 1):

This may work for you. Loops through each div and compared it to your inputted ID. Tracks closest one, hides all divs, then displays the closest.

```
document.getElementById("inputField").addEventListener("change", function(){

   var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
   var closestDiv = -1;
   var inputId = document.getElementById("inputField").value;
   for(var i=0; i<divs.length; i++)
   {
      if(Math.abs(inputId - closestDiv) > Math.abs(inputId - divs[i].id) || closestDiv == -1)
      {
         closestDiv = divs[i].id;
         for (var x = 0; x < divs.length; x++) {
            divs[x].style.display = 'none';        
         }
         divs[i].style.display = "block";
      }
    }
});
```

**See it Live:** [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/bhrmohtf/1/)

Comment: I like the answer; one problem is the way you have it set up with the -1 and the if statement, if the input number is <= 499 nothing shows up. Also I think you wrote innerDivs[i].id rather than inputId on the left side of the equality, and you don't convert the id from a string to a number.

Comment: Good catch! Ideas how to fix that?

Comment: If you look at my answer below, one way is to set closestDiv equal to the first div in the array right off the bat. So just `closestDiv = parseInt(divs[0].id)` instead of -1

Comment: I really like both answers.Do you guys know which one is the fastest method?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bhrmohtf/1/, is that fast enough for your use case? Thanks @JeremyE. for that catch. Works perfect now.

Comment: It's basically negligible, but my answer is faster because there are fewer calls, I don't get the length of the array and I don't search the index of the item in the array.  The difference is just looping through the items of an array vs. looping through the range of the array's length and then looking up the index.    EDIT: I also might be very wrong about that, not all languages are equal, I believe that's true for Python, but Javascript is much less clean.

Comment: I tested with an array of length 6 million, for looping through the array it was between 733-772ms, for looping through the range of length of the array it was 740-778ms. **Not a peer-reviewed scientific study**

Comment: That is very cool! How do you go about that? Do mine if you have the test open still

Comment: @SterlingBeason To test the time of something on javascript one thing you can do is write `console.time('some string');` before the function call, and `console.timeEnd('same string')` after the function call and it will print `Your String: Time it took`

Answer (score 1):

With some optimization this shall be ok-

```js
var element;
document.addEventListener("change",
function(evt){
if(element && element.classList){
element.classList.remove("selected", false); 
element.classList.add("unselected", true); 

}
var listOfDivs = 
document.querySelectorAll(".unselected");


var val = evt.target.value;

var leastAbs=listOfDivs[0].id;


for(let anIndex=0, len=listOfDivs.length;anIndex<len;anIndex++){
       
       if(Math.abs(listOfDivs[anIndex].id-val)<leastAbs){
       leastAbs = Math.abs(listOfDivs[anIndex].id-val);
       element = listOfDivs[anIndex];
       }
}
element.classList.remove("unselected");
element.classList.add("selected");

});
```

```css
.selected{
  background-color:red;
}
.unselected{
  background-color:yellow;
}

.unselected, .selected{
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<input id="inputField" type="number" value="">


<div id="1000" class='unselected'>1</div>
<div id="1200" class='unselected'>2</div>
<div id="1500" class='unselected'>3</div>
<div id="1900" class='unselected'>4</div>
```